# Display birthdays this month (again)

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I want to display birthdays this month from list items.

I have a form where we add birthdays manual. This just for Jubilee birthdays (50/65, big thing in Sweden)

Since there is a lot of hits when googling this problem and no solution that works.

But from some guides I tried to compare columns with no luck.

From birthday date I have a calculated column that takes out month (MMMMM) so i get "november" in an Single line output.

I have done the same with todays Date and there i got the same calculated that gives me month in a Single line output.

Then i make a 3rd calculated column and tries

```
This is what i tried `=EXACT([Column1],[Column2])`
```

I have tried diffrent versions of this with IF and "yes,"no" with no luck.

> The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported.

It can not be this hard too display birthdays from a specific month. I can not add webparts either.

**Solution is posted below**

Comment: Did you try ; instead of , in =EXACT([Column1],[Column2])? It depends what your regional settings are, so someone has , instead of ; and the others have opposite.

Comment: Life saver! It worked and the solution works perfect.

Comment: I will add it as solution in answer so others can also know it works.

Comment: I added a solution with all my steps. I think i got it right. I am just glad it is working. I tried alot of diffrent solutions that could be found online. None of them worked. This takes a bit of work but it works fine. 


Now i just want it to collect the data from the active directory DB but that is a task for the future.

Comment: --edit

I realized that my work was not correct. I looked to be working but when i used "Todays date" with in a list it is not updated with the actual date of "Today" but the date when the list entry was saved. 

I guess i have to use JS to look up the birthday month and then check todays month. Then view the list with CQWP and read a html file maybe that utilize the list and JS and maybe css to do the list nice.

But i want this to work without this. Seems impossible to get the current month from calculated.

Comment: there are other ideas how to refresh Today or Now() column. One of methods is to create Time scheduler event that calls powershell script, which will go through the list/library and update Today's column.

Answer (score 1):

Try **;** instead of **,** in **=EXACT([Column1],[Column2])**.
So it will work as
`=EXACT([Column1];[Column2])`